# Xamarin UI test, NUnit version unspported?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to run a test I get the following internal error:

[image]

I have the following packages installed:

```
    <packages>
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="NUnit" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Xamarin.UITest" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    </packages>
```

Comment: Running within the IDE's NUnit Pad would require version 2.4.x as that version is bound to the IDE. External to the IDE, you of course can use 2.x or 3.x

Comment: that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

by RobertN:

Running within the IDE's NUnit Pad would require version 2.4.x as that version is bound to the IDE. External to the IDE, you of course can use 2.x or 3.x